# For a .xib file, how do I know what class is the file's owner?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

Often, we need to connect outlets and actions with a .xib's File's Owner class.

How do I know what class is the file's owner for each .xib?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the xib, then on the left side select files owner

[image]

On the right side on the inspector select the third icon from the left check screen shot, ther e is the class of the file owner

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Identity Inspector

**(Cmd+Option+3)** and check the Class name.

It will show the owner of the xib file.